# Microsoft bluetooth mouse on RHEL6

Tags: linux, mouse, bluetooth, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am using rhel6 and I have a [bluetooth mouse](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msca/en_CA/pdp/productID.314457900?srccode=cii_363499683&cpncode=43-70830561-2&WT.mc_id=PLA_CAEN_GooglePLA) from microsoft
I am trying to pair it on my system but my system won't recognize it. I have followed up with some information which might help with the solution.

```
$ lsusb | grep Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0a5c:21e6 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702 Bluetooth 4.0 [ThinkPad]
$ rpm -qa | grep bluez
bluez-libs-4.66-1.el6.x86_64
bluez-4.66-1.el6.x86_64
$ rpm -qa | grep bluetooth
gnome-bluetooth-libs-2.28.6-8.el6.x86_64
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth-0.9.21-21.el6.x86_64
gnome-bluetooth-2.28.6-8.el6.x86_64
$ hcitool dev
Devices:
    hci0    44:6D:57:C2:33:27
```

Has anyone ever connected to this mouse before? In the compatibility list it shows it can connect to Android 4.4, which means it works with linux.